# jquery datatable column header not update properly

Tags: datatables

I try reuse 1 table with different amount of data based on different button click, I able to populate data successfully, but the problem is, the header did not populate correctly, I had debug and see the correct amount of column pass into table, but why it still retain the design from the 1st click? the 1st data from the 1st click have 3 column, but in the 2nd click, it still retain the same 3 column instead of 8 column? how to make the header populate correctly?

I try to destroy and recreate, but the code not working well if declare before the table create, any idea?

```
 //if ($.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable($(selector)[0])) {
            //    $(selector).dataTable.fnClearTable();
            //    $(selector).dataTable.fnDraw();
            //}

var oDataTable = $(selector).dataTable({
                "sDom": _sDom,
                "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bStateSave": true,
                "bSort": tools,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "sAjaxSource": source,
                "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                    aoData.push({ "name": "sParams", "value": params });
                },
                "bProcessing": true,
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sLengthMenu": _displayLen
                },
                "aoColumns": cols
            });
```

**1st button click**
[image]

**2nd button click** 
[image]

Comment: No idea or I cannot reuse the same table for multiple ajax request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found the answer, after fndestroy, I still need to remove header from table before recreate a new set of header

```
$(selector).find('thead tr th').remove();
```